# video not found or access denied in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

In my Rails application, I'm trying to add video like below:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th width="25%">Candidate</th>
        <th width="80%">Video</th>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <%= video_player({:file => "/assets/video/water_msg.flv"}, {:width => 470, :height => 400, :id => "water_msg_video", :onclick => "alert('clicked!');"}) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
       </table>
```

I'm using relative path like above in `:file` but I'm getting error below:

```
video not found or access denied: /assets/video/water_msg.flv
```

When I use full path (or link) instead of relative path like `http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4`, the video plays. What should I do?

Comment: Put your video in `public` folder, and change `:file => "/video/water_msg.flv"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the path without `/assets/` like this:

```
<%= video_player({:file => "video/water_msg.flv"}, {:width => 470, :height => 400, :id => "water_msg_video", :onclick => "alert('clicked!');"}) %>
```